# Whatsapp freezes trying to post from iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, whatsapp

I've developed an iOS app that uses Whatsapp to send invitations to friends.
I'm using this code:

```
NSString *myURL = @"whatsapp://send?text=blablabla";
NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
```

Whatsapp opens, the user can select one of his/her contacts, click on Send and then the message appears in his/her board. Everything is ok.

But my client is testing this with his iPhone 6 and Whatsapp always freezes when he clicks on Send, he has to kill Whatsapp.

Looking at the XCode log, this is what I see related to whatsapp when he clicks on Send:

```
Sep 15 12:55:30 Gins-iphone WhatsApp[1395] <Warning>: _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
Sep 15 12:55:30 Gins-iphone WhatsApp[1395] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: BaseBoard + 251204 [B6F2014B-5644-3053-8F52-52776ACFA530]: 0x14
Sep 15 12:55:30 Gins-iphone Unknown[1395] <Error>: 
Sep 15 12:55:30 Gins-iphone WhatsApp[1395] <Error>: assertion failed: 13G36: BaseBoard + 251204 [B6F2014B-5644-3053-8F52-52776ACFA530]: 0xf
Sep 15 12:55:30 Gins-iphone Unknown[1395] <Error>: 
Sep 15 12:55:30 Gins-iphone WhatsApp[1395] <Warning>: _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
Sep 15 12:55:38 Gins-iphone SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted
Sep 15 12:55:38 Gins-iphone SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: UNNotificationRegistrarConnectionListener connection invalidated
Sep 15 12:55:38 Gins-iphone SpringBoard[58] <Warning>: UNNotificationSchedulerConnectionListener connection invalidated
Sep 15 12:55:38 Gins-iphone mediaserverd[28] <Notice>: '' net.whatsapp.WhatsApp(pid = 1395) setting DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
```

In one of our tests I see this error too:

```
Attempting to send an xpc message to a suspended client whatsapp
```

I'm sure that this problem is not related to my app but with Whatsapp but my client is worried and I don't know what to check. 
Any idea of what could I see?

EDIT 1: Despite I was thinking that this was a random error I've been able to detect when it occurs. Whatsapp always freezes if the user search his/her contact using the Whatsapp search. If my user search the contact clicks on it and then on Send, Whatsapp freezes.
But if my users clicks on a contact directly without using the search bar and then clicks on Send, it always works right. 
I hope this is a clue but I don't have any idea yet.

EDIT 2: More detail. If fact the problem is not when my user use the Whatsapp search but when my user selects a contact **with the search keyboard open**.
If my user search a contact, closes the keyboard and clicks on that contact Whatsapp works good.
I'm pretty sure this is a 100% Whatsapp problem, not my apps problem, but if I could do anything from my app it would be great.

Kind regards!

Comment: Did you add "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" to you plist? also add condition to check if whatsapp is installed or not https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: Yes, I've included both things.